# Data structure alternative to malloc() function in c++

Tags: c++

In Data structure ad algorithm There are various linked list operations that allow us to perform different actions on linked lists includes the insertion operation which adds a new element to the linked list.

this example here demonstrates the implementation of linked list operation in C programming language , however the same logic / idea can also be implemented in C ++ ,

assume we want to implement this logic with c++ , what will be alternative to this line in c++?

`malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

```
struct node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = 4;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
```

Comment: *Data structure alternative* -- Your issue is not a "data structures" one.   Do you know what `malloc` does?  If you do, you then should know what `new` does in C++.

Comment: the alternative in C++ is to use `std::list`  (or `std::vector`)

Comment: ```std::shared_ptr<node> newNode = std::make_shared<node>();``` Can also used for creating new object without thinking the deletion of the object. But node should be defined as a class. However if you insist to use value type with struct you should be aware of delete of all objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try `node *newNode = new node();`